# Converting forEach in Ionic 2 to an acceptable format

Tags: angularjs, ionic2

In ionic 1 I was using this in my js file to go through a JSON called response. Response comes from the API

```
angular.forEach(response,function(child)
 {
   $scope.result.push(child);
 })
```

and in my html, I used ng-repeat to iterate through the items

```
<div  ng-repeat="res in result">
...
</div>
```

How do I write this in Ionic 2.

I have tried this:

```
this.listProvider.searchResult(this.data)
        .then((response) => {

        Object.keys(response).forEach(key=> {
            this.list.push(response[key])
        });

    }, (err) => {
        console.log ('err' + err)
    })
```

and this in the html

```
<ion-card  *ngFor=" let item of list">
```

but I get so many errors

Comment: Can you add the content of the response?